# Configuring crafter-delivery profile

Tags: crafter-cms

We need our active directory to manage the autentication from the site, is there a way to configure the crafter-delivery profile/security in a way like we can do in studio?

```
Users added to the internal database after the user’s first successful login through external authentication are marked as **Externally Managed**.
```

There is no engine-config-override.yaml so i dont know how to do it.

The documentation says something about it, but its not explained anywhere.

> Crafter Profile is built on MongoDB for extensibility and extreme
>   scalability and includes a multi-tenant profile attribute store, an
>   admin console for user profile management, chained authentication with
>   any existing authentication services including **Active Directory**

https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/developers/projects/profile/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crafter Engine uses Crafter Security Provider library, which can be extended to support LDAP/AD.

Another, perhaps easier/better option is to just use SAML2 and not only will the users authenticate against AD, but they'll also get SSO.

Here is the guide: https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/site-administrators/engine/engine-site-security-guide.html#add-single-sign-on